# Porting to ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

Our website is implemented in ASP and Visual Basic.

I wish to add a few new pages to the site but I wish to do it in ASP .NET MVC with C#. Are ASP and ASP.NET compatible for the same website?

I've done a few ASP .NET MVC tutorials. What would I need to do to get a simple hello world project to work on our server? What will I need to install etc?

Also, our database is implemented for sql server 9.0. Will there be any issues here?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: Please pay attention to your tag choices. The `asp` tag proved to be ambigious, and so was cleaned out in favor of `asp-classic`. For a moment there, you had the **only** question on the site tagged `asp`, and that helps no one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are ASP and ASP.NET compatible for the same website

The same IIS Web Application can include both ASP and ASP.NET pages.

But nothing will be shared, `Session` and `Application` objects are completely separate. To share code it will need to be COM components, and use the .NET tools to create a wrapper.

> SQL Server 9.0

That's 2005: fully supported in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a few bits to the Richard answer:

- Create a MVC app and copy over all the asp files
- Edit the `global.asax` and add the following line in `RegisterRoutes`

  ```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asp/{*pathInfo}");
  ```
- If the root of the site will continue to be an ASP file you have to deal with the routing also